# How to align a button to the center with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So my image is fullscreen (except for the footer) and my button is in the middle. It was working all fine, my button was in the center but now that I have started working with bootstrap and changed my button, my button is shifted all the way to the left of the screen and not the center... does anyone have any solutions?

note: I have tried doing

```
 <div class="wrapper text-center">
```

and still it wouldn't work.

Here is a screenshot I took: https://gyazo.com/ce68d7b118156371ad02e7aa2a33ec2a

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>


        <title>
        project
        </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
    </head>


    <body>




    <div class="wrapper">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Facebook</button>
        </div>

        <div class="footer"></div>

      <div class="download">Download</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

then...

```
    html,body{
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
      }
    .wrapper {
               display:flex;
               align-items:center; 
               width:100%;
               height:100%;
               background-image: url("../img/space.jpg");
               background-repeat:no-repeat;
               background-size:cover;

         }

        .button {
          width:100px;
          margin:auto;
        }

        .footer {

    padding-top: 200px;

        }

        .download {
          float: top;
        }
```

Comment: you want the button centered vertically or horizontally

Comment: @Naila it's already centered vertically via `align-items: center;`. I'm assuming they mean centered horizontally.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thanks for your information

Comment: I already got it. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Add `justify-content: center;` to `.wrapper`

```css
html,
body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: url("../img/space.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
justify-content: center;
}
.button {
width: 100px;
margin: auto;
}
.footer {
padding-top: 200px;
}
.download {
float: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
         project
      </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Facebook</button>
      </div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
      <div class="download">Download</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this with `margin:0 auto;`

```
.btn {
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url("../img/space.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
.button {
 width: 100px;
 margin: 0 sauto;
}
.btn {
 margin:0 auto;
}
.footer {
 padding-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="wrapper">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Facebook</button>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
<div class="download">Download</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to bootstrap. That worked though, thank you!

Comment: @mdlz michael coker answer was also nice with flex property try that also